# Area under the Curve (Sin/Cos Graphs)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The question is :

Find the area between the curves y = $\sin(2x)$ and y = $\cos^2(x)$ in the interval $0 < x < 2\pi$

---

What I have done is find intersection points

$$ \sin(2x) = \cos^2(x) $$

$$ 2\sin(x)\cos(x) = \cos^2(x) $$

$$ \cos^2(x) - 2\sin(x)\cos(x) = 0 $$

$$ \cos(x)(\cos(x) - 2\sin(x)) = 0 $$

$$ \cos(x) = 0 , \tan(x) = 1/2 $$

Therefore $x = \pi/2$ , $x = 0.46$ , $x = 3.6$ $x = 3\pi/2 $

By using desmos:[image]

Would I have to do 5 separate integrals or is there a trick of doing less integrals and getting the same answer?

Comment: You can notice that both functions are periodic with period $\pi$, so you really only need to calculate the area between the curves on the interval $0<x<\pi$ then double it.

Comment: So I do 3 integrals and multiply by 2? (from 0.464 - 0 , pi/2 - 0.464 and pi - pi/2)

Comment: That's a possibility. As @Aganju noted in the answer below, two integrals will suffice if you're clever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because both functions are periodic over $2\pi$, you can take *any* interval of length $2\pi$. If you chose $\pi/2$ to $3\pi/2$, you only have to do 2 integrals - from $\pi/2$ to the intersection at ~3.6, and from there to $3\pi/2$.

You can't make it in one integral, because 'the area between' changes its direction, and a single integral would count it negative when the other curve is 'on top', which is not what you want.

In addition, you only need to solve the indefinite integral of the difference once, and then use the result in two definite integrals (one +, the other -)

Comment: If I took 2 integrals (one from pi/2 to 3.6 and from 3.6 to 3pi/2) would I multiply the answer by 2?

Comment: no, you already have integrated over a $2\pi$ range, so you are good. - someone else proposed to only integrate half the range; then you would multiply by 2. It wouldn't make things any easier though.